# Heroku - Build failed - npm ERR! code EBADENGINE

Tags: heroku, vuejs3

I've had this problem for many days and I don't know how to solve it.
I always get the same error.

```
remote: npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
remote: npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
remote: npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.2.1
remote: npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.2.1
remote: npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0"}
remote: npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"9.6.3","node":"v19.9.0"}
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /tmp/npmcache.IoBfB/_logs/2023-10-26T12_15_46_220Z-debug-0.log
remote:        Unable to install npm >=6.0.0.  Does npm >=6.0.0 exist?  Is npm >=6.0.0 compatible with this Node.js version?
```

The version of my nodejs is v20.8.1
The version of my npm is 10.2.1
And this is my package.json ...

```html
{
  "name": "ecommerce",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.14.4",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.14.4",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.14.4",
    "better-sqlite3": "8.6.0",
    "debug": "^4.3.4",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "45f08ee7-c335-4c95-a7f2-66d18d42b85b"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0 <=20.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Comment: it's not _your_ version of node that's the problem, it's heroku's.  https://help.heroku.com/6235QYN4/why-is-my-node-js-build-failing-because-of-no-matching-node-versions

Comment: I also update the heroku version. :-(

Comment: Would you care to show how you went about doing that and updating your question with the updated error log? You have to show your work if you want help making possible corrections.

Comment: I have already put the package.json.  The project with strapi is new. (npx create-strapi-app ecommerce)

Comment: If you read your error message, the required node is `Required: {"node":"^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0"}`, which is in simplified terms is "node 18 OR node >=20".  According to your package.json you are providing a range "node between 16 and 20".  You see then how heroku can pick node 19 given your range and it not meet the requirement of the error message? What is the reason in even providing a range at all?  Pick the exact node version you know works, `"node": "20.8.1"`. Match your production environment to your dev environment as close as possible to avoid errors and inconsistencies.